# Array.sort only returns 0 values. Correct sized array and array is fully filled

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

Sorry for another one of these threads, but was reading through what is out there and nothing answered my question. I have some very basic code just taking in 5 values, sorting them and doing some math with the 3 middle ones and finally outputting something. Not hard, but for some reason my Array.sort only returns the value 0. I'm pretty sure all spots in the array are filled before sorting and that my array is the correct size. Suggestions?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

    public class practice {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int[] finals = new int[3];
            int[] scores = new int[5];
            int difficulty = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                System.out.println("Please input the scores for diver " + (x + 1));

                for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
                    scores[x] = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(scores[x]);
                }
                Arrays.sort(scores);
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    System.out.println(scores[x]);
                }
                System.out.println("Please input the difficult of diver " + (x + 1));
                difficulty = scanner.nextInt();
                finals[x] = (((scores[1] * scores[2] * scores[3]) / 3) * difficulty);
                System.out.println(finals[x]);
            }
            winner(finals);

        }

        public static void winner(int[] finals) {
            System.out.println(finals[0]);
            if (finals[0] > finals[2] && finals[0] > finals[1]) {
                System.out.println("Diver 1 is the winner of the olympics with a score of " + finals[0]);
            } else if (finals[1] > finals[2] && finals[1] > finals[0]) {
                System.out.println("Diver 2 is the winner of the olympics with a score of " + finals[1]);
            } else if (finals[2] > finals[0] && finals[2] > finals[1]) {
                System.out.println("Diver 3 is the winner of the olympics with a score of " + finals[2]);
            } else {
                System.out.println("There was a tie");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The problem is with the line scores[x] = scanner.nextInt(). Should you not use 'y' for the index when reading the values into the array?

Comment: Also I suggest you to use a IDE debugger to step through your code and identify the defect

Answer (score 1):

This,

```
for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
    scores[x] = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(scores[x]);
}
```

should be

```
for (int y = 0; y < scores.length; y++) {
    scores[y] = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(scores[y]);
}
```

**don't** rely on hardcoded length(s). And note which variable you are ***iterating***. You made a very *similar* mistake here

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    System.out.println(scores[x]);
}
```

should be

```
for (int j = 0; j < scores.length; j++) {
    System.out.println(scores[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is two fold.

In your for loop

```
for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
     scores[x] = scanner.nextInt();
     System.out.println(scores[x]);
}
```

you keep adding your score to the same space (in this case 0) in the scores array.  Where you have x in the code, it should be y to be able to  add all 5 scores into your array as follows:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
    scores[y] = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(scores[y]);
}
```

You have made the same mistake in printing out your scores in this code, where you are again only printing x, which is from your outside loop and at this point still the same (in this case still 0):

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    System.out.println(scores[x]);
}
```

Your code here should read:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    System.out.println(scores[j]);
}
```

This means that you will then loop through all 5 scores in your array.

The rest all looks good and would run fine.

Although it is best practice to use scores.length instead of 5 in the constraints of these two loops.